# How Angular manages non-Angular instances

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a question about how Angular manages the injection of non-Angular "things" when we try to inject them into a component.

In particular, let's take an example and use the ngx-modialog library (https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog) for Angular (I'm using version 6)

This is all straightforward if I follow the Quikcstart guide of the library. However, note this part:

```
constructor(public modal: Modal) { }
```

- So, my question is how does the `Modal` instance get injected into our AppComponent constructor ?

  Or, a more generic question is, how does Angular "provide" instances of these non-service classes / functions ?
- My second question is, will these injections of type "prototype" (new instance for new components that we try to inject to ?)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: I read that part, but it's about services. I'm asking about non-services ...

Comment: Modal is the superclass of a service. So it finds the service that is of type Modal and injects that. See https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog/blob/master/projects/demo/src/app/home/in-app-plugin/index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I  have a question about how Angular manages the injection of non-Angular "things" when we try to inject them into a component.

Everything that is *injectable* is referred to as a *provider* in Angular. Each *provider* is presented as a *pair* of information.

- what identifies the provider
- what value is the provider

Angular needs to first *identify* a provider and then it needs to give the *value*. An *identifier* is a JavaScript value that satisfies an `===` expression, and the *value* is any JavaScript type (i.e. object, array, string, number, function).

We can use a class constructor function as the *identifier* since it satisfies an `===` expression.

For example;

```js
class MyService {}
// assume MyService is provided via a NgModule somewhere
const x: Type<MyService> = MyService;
console.log(x === MyService); // prints true
console.log(injector.get(x)); // prints MyService instance
console.log(injector.get(MyService)); // prints same MyService instance as above
```

When we *provide* a class constructor as the *identifier* for a provider it is referred to as a *service*. Using classes with dependency injection is the most common practice, and we call them services because it's easier to understand.

> So, my question is how does the Modal instance get injected into our AppComponent constructor ?

It only works because you added a `@Component({...})` decorator to the top of the class.

TypeScript will call a class decorator when the class prototype is first declared. The decorator is a JavaScript function that receives the prototype as an argument. Angular at this stage inspects the prototype which has a constructor function. Using a reference to the constructor function Angular can see how many arguments there are and the their types.

Remember above where I showed how the class constructor can be used to fetch an instance from the injector. The `@Component()` decorator does the same with the constructor function to fetch an instance of the *modal*. It modifies the original constructor function, fetches injectable values and passes the values as arguments. All of this is possible, because we have special features in TypeScript enabled by default when we create an Angular project.

> Or, a more generic question is, how does Angular "provide" instances of these non-service classes / functions ?

There are different types of *providers* in Angular. Some are static values, some are factory functions and there are class providers. If the type `Modal` is a class provider, then Angular will create a new instance the *first time* it is injected. The value is then cached and re-used afterwards by that *injector* instance.

> My second question is, will these injections of type "prototype" (new instance for new components that we try to inject to ?)

Angular creates a *tree* of injectors. When a *provider* is fetched the injectors search the *tree* until an injector for that *provider* is found. Depending upon the type of provider (see above) a *value* is read. If it is a class type, then a new instance is created and cached by that injector.

If there are no injectors that provide that type then an injection error that the type is unknown is raised.

### Where does Modal come from?

`Modal` is an *abstract* class but they still have a *unique* constructor function, and that can be used as an *identifier* for the provider.

The library you're using has plugins that provide functionality for the `Modal` class. For example; the bootstrap plugin has a module that declares a *provider* for the `Modal` class. You can see in the source code that they've replaced the default class with a *different* class by using a custom class provider.

https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog/blob/44f16f73a5418ac3c41f4ebbc3ed58538a1adea5/projects/plugins/bootstrap/src/lib/bootstrap.module.ts#L17

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll need to re-read the docs more carefully indeed. Some tutorials that I read just focus on "services" so they misled us to think in term of services only.

Comment: @ramcrys you're welcome. Please upvote if you found the post useful.